# clear button on text field not accessible with voice over - swift

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, textfield, voiceover

I'm trying to make the clear button of the text field accessible by voice over, but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone had this issue before? It's a simple text field on a blank screen.

It works fine on my contacts list when I try to add a number. How could I access the button to set its accessibilityElement to true, if that's the case?

Comment: Can you share the code? As it should work by default.

Comment: I don't have the code anymore, unfortunately. It was on a project I worked a while ago.